# Is there a way to sandbox parts of a java process on Android?

Tags: java, android, appdomain

I want to use an SDK in android, but I don't want that SDK to have any access to permissions that I haven't explicitly given it.  On top of that, if the SDK throws an uncaught exception, I don't want it to bring down my entire application.

In C# there is the concept of an AppDomain where you can treat the code running inside of it like a sandbox, granting (or limiting) permissions, and only providing access to data that you explicitly want to share.

Is there anything that works like this in Java for the Android platform?

Comment: why -1 for this question?I have up voted it

Comment: :-) Thanks.  It was down to -2 for some reason.  Haters gotta hate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions here. The first one deals with handling exceptions in a piece of untrusted code; a carefully written try/catch block should take care of that, as long as the untrusted piece is pure Java. If native code is allowed, then nothing short of process level isolation would help. For running code in a separate process, read up on Android services; you can designate a service to run in a designated process. Then exceptions (the nonmanaged kind) won't bring down the main app. You'll just get a "service has died" exception.

A whole another issue is lowering the permission set. To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to lower the permission set within an app. Even a surrogate process won't help. If you ship a whole *application* (in the Android sense of the word) for wrapping and running custom code, that might help. But the logistics of app installation would get tricky. Google Market does not readily support the notion of app interdependence or prerequisites.

Comment: Good point about the service, I think that will also catch situations where the library brings up separate threads (which this one does).  The permissioning is unfortunate though.  I'm going to leave this open a bit longer, maybe there's some magic invocation that's not highly publicized, and *does* work.

Comment: If you're after not highly publicized stuff, start digging in the Android sources.

Answer (score 0):

All the permissions you give to your app are the permissions that are allowed to otherwise it wont have permissions for almost nothing.
you set your permissions in your `Manifest.xml` otherwise than that you cannot set other kind of permissions.

Comment: Yes, I want an SDK I use to only have access to a subset of those permissions.